# flutter animatins running very slow on some devices?

Tags: android, flutter

I have tested my app on about ten android devices, and I don't know why on some devices it executes animation really slow, and on some devices it executes just fine, and it's not about the API level it's not about the GPU, but the overall result in some devices is majorly different.
for example here is the list

It is a branch of this github repository: 
[github page](https://github.com/amirh/indux/tree/master/examples/2048)

- Galaxy j7 2016 (smooth)
- Xperia Z3 (slow)
- Huawei Hol-u19 (fine)
- Galaxy Tab S2 (terrible)
- Techno W1 dual sim (good)
- LG V500 (bad)

I have no idea why.

Here is my code for animations, in case if it can help you guys:

```
 Animation<Alignment> alignment = new Tween(
            begin: new Alignment(fromXPosition, fromYPosition),
            end: new Alignment(toXPosition, toYPosition))
        .animate(new CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Curves.linear,
      parent: slideController,
    ));
    slideController.forward();

    Animation<double> fadeAnimation;
    if (fadeIn) {
      fadeAnimation =
          new CurvedAnimation(parent: fadeController, curve: Curves.linear);
      fadeController.forward();
    } else {
      fadeAnimation = new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1.0);
    }
    return new AlignTransition(
        child: new FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 0.25,
          heightFactor: 0.25,
          child: new FadeTransition(
            opacity: fadeAnimation,
            child: new Tile(value),
          ),
        ),
        alignment: alignment);
```

I uploaded a video of profile mode with graph:[youtube-video](https://youtu.be/YoLSupCjMIc)

Comment: Are you calling `slideController.forward()` or `fadeController.forward()` from the `build` method?

Comment: it depends on the situation @boformer

Comment: To see if this is actually a device-specific issue or something related to your code, you should start with something simple, e.g. a simple fade animation. If it runs without a problem on all devices, start slowly adding things until the problem occurs.

Comment: Starting animation controllers from the `build` method is plainly wrong. It might happen that your widgets are rebuilt frequently, that's why you should NEVER do state changes from a `build` method.